# Bootstrap datepicker - converting between internal and display values

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm using Bootstrap's Datepicker on an input element, and was wondering - Is there was a way to display the date in a different format from how I might set the date in or get the date from the input element?  The date comes to me from my data source in the format `yyyymmdd`, but I'd like to display the date as `mm/dd/yyyy` in the input element.  For example:

- The date I'd like to initially seed the input element with is `20150721`.
- After setting that value, it's actually displayed as `07/21/2015`.
- The user changes it with the picker to `07/28/2015`.
- I get the value from the element as `20150728`.

Is there a way to perform this format mapping using Bootstrap's datepicker?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, you can share your script on snippet ?

Comment: [https://jsfiddle.net/x4tLb0gr/](https://jsfiddle.net/x4tLb0gr/)
In this fiddle, the datepicker accepts a value in the format 'yyyymmdd' and also displays the date in the same format in the input element.  I'd actually like it to display in a different format (mm/dd/yyyy), but be able to set/get the date to/from the element in the current format.  Does that make sense?  If one of the options was a secondary 'displayFormat', then it would be exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/release/options.html#format), just set the format property.

```
 $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        format: 'mmd/dd/yyyy',
 })
```

Comment: This changes the display format, yes.  But that means I need to set the date in that same format, and when I get the selected date, it comes to me in that format.  I actually want to set/get the date in one format ('yyyymmdd'), but display it in another ('mm/dd/yyyy').

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is your solution:

```js
var _date = '20150721';
$('#_date').datepicker({
    autoclose: true,
    clearBtn: true,
    format: 'mm/dd/yyyy'
});
$('#_date').datepicker('setDate', _date);
$('#_test').click(function () {
    alert($('#_date').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<input id='_date'><button id='_test'>Test</button>
```